# How can I use java.lang.instrument in an Eclipse RCP application?

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp, instrumentation

In order to use the instrumentation features introduced in JDK 5, you can use the `-javaagent` flag passed to the JVM. This will inject an instance of an Instrumentation class into the static `premain` method. For example in a class like this:

```
public class MyClass {
    public static Instrumentation inst;
    public static void premain(String options, Instrumentation inst) {
        MyClass.inst = inst;
    }
}
```

With an appropriate manifest file, you can run this as follows:

```
 java -javaagent:myfiles.jar SomeClass
```

This calls the premain method then `main` from `SomeClass`. This approach is used in the [Java.SizeOf Project](http://sizeof.sourceforge.net/) to guess at the approximate size of a Java object.

OK, now in Eclipse RCP [each bundle has its own classloader](http://www.eclipsezone.com/articles/eclipse-vms/). This means that the static Instrumentation that we stored in our MyClass is not visible to an Eclipse application. The javaagent uses one class-loader, the Eclipse bundles get loaded with another. When we access `MyClass.inst` from within a plugin it is `null`, as *that* class is not the same class as the one the javaagent loaded and called `premain` on.

Other clues as to a possible solution are [this thread](http://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/newsLists/news.eclipse.platform.rcp/msg18358.htm) on the rcp mailing list. But nothing conclusive.

Is there any way to work around this? The `Eclipse-BuddyPolicy` hinted at in the eclipsezone article sounds good. I tried:

```
Eclipse-BuddyPolicy: app
```

in my plugins without luck. I need something like `Eclipse-BuddyPolicy: javaagent`. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you receive any exeptions? One pitfall is having the agent class without a package. (i.e. MyClass may not be in default package). Does it work outside eclipse?

Comment: Yep, works fine outside Eclipse with POJO stuff. In fact, a "println" in the premain gets shown from Eclipse, but then the static Instrumentation is null when called from any plugin.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the simplest solution is to use the global properties object. Have pre-main store the instrumentation object as a global properties and then access it from everywhere (the properties object is the same in all class loaders):

[Edit: updated]

```
public class MyClass {
    private static final String KEY = "my.instrumentation";
    public static void premain(String options, Instrumentation inst) {
        Properties props = System.getProperties();
        if(props.get(KEY) == null)
           props.put(KEY, inst);
    }

    public static Instrumentation getInstrumentation() { 
       return System.getProperties().get(KEY);
    }
}
```