# Getting loaded class names from JVM

Tags: java, spring, jvm

I want to get all the **class names loaded in JVM** for my tomcat service. Is there any way to get it using java...
I have seen Reflection, but it's for a specific class loader and it's not giving classes loaded in JVM.

Comment: [JMX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Management_Extensions) I guess

Answer (score 1):

The canonical way to get all loaded classes from Java is to call [`Instrumentation.getAllLoadedClasses()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.instrument/java/lang/instrument/Instrumentation.html#getAllLoadedClasses()) from the [Instrumentation API](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.instrument/java/lang/instrument/package-summary.html).

However, this requires an instance of `Instrumentation`, which is available only to Java Agents. If you can't (or don't want to) start your application with an agent, it's possible to attach [ByteBuddyAgent](https://javadoc.io/doc/net.bytebuddy/byte-buddy-agent/latest/net/bytebuddy/agent/ByteBuddyAgent.html) in runtime:

```
Instrumentation inst = ByteBuddyAgent.install();
Class[] loadedClasses = inst.getAllLoadedClasses();
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I haven't checked it, but I can solve the problem by following on to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2065626/15610843

Answer (score -1):

You can see [Enable Logging with the JVM Unified Logging Framework](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/tools/java.htm#JSWOR-GUID-BE93ABDC-999C-4CB5-A88B-1994AAAC74D5)
and do like this

```
java -Xlog:class+load=info:classloaded.txt
```